# What syntax should be used for Harry Potter game tags?

Tags: support, tags

Since the game titles are lengthy, shortening or abbreviations are necessary. The "mainline" [Harry Potter games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter#Games):

> - Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
> - Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
> - Harry Potter: Quidditch World Cup
> - Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
> - Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
> - Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix
> - Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince
> - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 1
> - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2

Even as a person familiar with the franchise, abbreviations "HPB", "POA" and "QWC" aren't instantly recognizable to me. Adding tag info may be necessary for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any current questions it's hard to judge what people would want to use, but here's my take:

Fully written out, most of those games won't fit under our 35 character limit as-is. But if we drop the least important part of the names, (the "`and-the-`") all tags fit under 35 characters:

- [harry-potter-philosophers-stone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-philosophers-stone) (31)
- [harry-potter-chamber-of-secrets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-chamber-of-secrets) (31)
- [harry-potter-quidditch-world-cup](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-quidditch-world-cup) (32)
- [harry-potter-prisoner-of-azkaban](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-prisoner-of-azkaban) (32)
- [harry-potter-goblet-of-fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-goblet-of-fire) (27)
- [harry-potter-order-of-the-phoenix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-order-of-the-phoenix) (33)
- [harry-potter-half-blood-prince](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-half-blood-prince) (30)
- [harry-potter-deathly-hallows-part-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-deathly-hallows-part-1) (35)
- [harry-potter-deathly-hallows-part-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-deathly-hallows-part-2) (35)

We could potentially look at creating shorthand, 'HP'-style synonyms, but let's cross that bridge when we actually have some questions for them.

Comment: I forgot that the tag length was increased, I ran my tests with 25.